# Trying to find the 2nd largest number in python using max function

Tags: python-3.x, function, max

so i have return this code -

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))    
# arr.sort(reverse = True)
arr1 = max(arr)
arr2 = max(arr, key=lambda x: min(arr)-1 if (x == arr1) else x)
print(arr2)
```

Unable to understand how this min(arr)-1 is helping out here.

Answer (score 1):

The logics behind the code you posted are to first find the largest number from the list with a normal call to `max`, and then find the second largest number by calling `max` again, but with a key function that by default returns the current number as the key, except that if it's the largest number, it returns a key that is guaranteed to be the smallest in the list so that it won't get returned by `max` again. In this case, the smallest number minus one is the key that is used by the code to make it the smallest of all.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression:

```py
arr2 = max(arr, key=lambda x: min(arr)-1 if (x == arr1) else x)
```

A lambda expression is being provided as the `key` argument to the `max()` function.  This means that this lambda will actually provide the values for the input `arr` list.  The lambda says that if the `x` value happens to be the maximum value, then replace it with the *minimum* value minus 1.  This effectively removes the maximum value from the list from being considered by the `max()` function.  This then leaves behind the second to highest value as the maximum value.

Another way to do this, which seems more intuitive to me, would be to use a list comprehension:

```py
arr2 = max([x for x in arr if x != max(arr)])
```

Here we just explicitly remove the max value and then let `max()` find the second to highest value.

Comment: thank you so much , alternative seems to be interesting as well.